# r.flow in QGIS 2.16.1 generates wrong output

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, length, flow, flow-accumulation

I try to run the r.flow module to get the flow path length of my layer out.
The input Layer is a DEM with pixelsize 0.0083 and the selected CRS (EPSG:32646, WGS 84/ UTM zone 46).
First of all I generated a depressionless elevation with saga:fill sinks.
If I start the function, it runs and I get the three Outputlayer, but they are wrong. -->  pictures see below

My Data: Win 10, Qgis 2.16.1 with Grass 7 Plugin.
I have the same problem if run r.flow in Grass.

Which additional steps I have to do ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could be a problem with projection. is your DEM really projected in epsg:32646 ? (with a pixel size of 0.0083 it seem unlikely)

Comment: If your are in UTM (=projected), it means you have a pixel size of 8 cm... Is that correct ?? Looks more like angular units to me.

Comment: I´ve already tried different projections. If I check up the pixel size and the projection it tells me the same I have mentioned. Actually the DEM was projected in WGS 84 but than it araises the 'ERROR: lat/long projection not supported by r.flow. Please use 'r.watershed' for calculating flow accumulation.'. So I´ve choosen a UTM projection. Which projection should I choose?